# $2^n-3^m=1 , m,n \in \mathbb N =?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

$2^n-3^m=1 , m,n \in \mathbb N =?$ my questions are:

1. do m,n exist?
2. are they finitely many $m,n$?
3. if there are infinitely many is there a way to describe them all?

Same question about $3^n-2^m=1 $, besides $m=n=1$ are there any others?

PS: This is not from number theory or home work, just personal pondering

Comment: What happens if you do the equality modulo $3$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : So rusty in that area, will review the mod and then review the question

Comment: It looks strange to me why you accepted Gottfried Helms' answer; it even didn't answer your question. However, anon provided a detailed full answer and Giraffe's hint could also easily lead you to a full answer.

Comment: @Landscape: why I didn't made (another) answer with a full featured prof is because there was already one. But I read the keyword "rusty" in Arjang's comment to Mariano, which made me thinking of something more focused on intuitivity and most basic guidance/refreshing of some simple/old(?) forgotten ideas. Perhaps that's why it's also accepted?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: Thank you for your explanation. It sounds quite reasonable. However, I still consider solving this question as a good opportunity for the OP to practice with modular arithmetic. By the way, Giraffe's answer avoids modular arithmetic.

Comment: @Landscape : I upvoted and accpeted the other answer, but  Gottfried's answer had something else in it that gives more usability. So yes as correct and beutifull the other answer are, Gottfried's answer helps out an old man to construct a net himself rather than only try to understand how to use FishMaster 10000 automatic fishing machine.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms : The ability to explicitly have an orderd list that I can look for patterns and examine intuitively would help me with many other things as well. Thank you

Comment: @Arjang: Thank for your reply. I respect your decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Update: Table & text a bit extended]*

I like to look at such questions in a, say, "constructive" way. First I change to the more familiar form
$$ 2^n = 3^m + 1$$ 
Now let *m* vary, we get, where *N* is the exponent at primefactor *2* in $3^m+1 (=x \cdot 2^N) $
 $$ \begin{array} {r|llll} 
 m & 0&1&2&3&4 & ... \\
 3^m+1 &2& 4 & 10 & 28 &82 & ... \\
 N & 1&2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & ...
 \end{array} $$
which can easily be extended to improve also intuition and finally might be proved by binomial expansion or by Fermat/Euler.
So we find, that N is only 2 or 1 and that's the highest power of *2* occuring in $3^m+1$ - but clearly we can then have at most two solutions, because we have only *2* different *N* - that first two possibilites found in the table above prove to be true solutions.

Comment: The pattern of $N$ always being $1$ or $2$ can also be proved by modular arithmetic. A handy fact is that squares of units mod $8$ are all $1$, and $3$ is a unit, hence the only powers of $3$ mod $8$ are $1$ and $3$, so here $2^n$ is congruent to either $1+1$ or $3+1$ mod $8$, hence $n<3$.

Answer (score 5):

$\mathsf{Hint}$: Consider mod 3, then mod 4, then mod 8.

---

> $\displaystyle\begin{array}{lllllll} \rm 2^n-3^m=1 & \implies & \rm (-1)^n\equiv 1\bmod 3 & \iff &  \rm 2\mid n & \iff & \rm n=2u \\ \rm 4^u-3^m=1 & \implies & \rm (-1)^m\equiv-1\bmod 4 & \iff & \rm 2\nmid m & \iff & \rm m=2v+1 \\ \rm 4^u-3\cdot 9^v=1 & \implies & \rm 4^u\equiv 4\bmod 8 & \iff & \rm u=1 &\implies & \rm n=2,m=1\end{array}$

Comment: If someone can figure out how to get spoilers working with LaTeX like this, that'd be great. Many an attempted spoiler of mine has been thwarted before.

Comment: The spoiler works for me now. I simply deleted the two newlines you got by hitting enter when typing the $\LaTeX$ code. The entire code for the array is now on a single line. Typing enter anywhere seems to break the spoiler, I don't know why.

Comment: @Martin Thanks, I should have considered that.

Comment: Nice with the hiding-mechanics!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

1. When $n$ is odd, $2^n-1=(3-1)^n-1$ cannot be divided by $3$.
2. When $n$ is even, say $n=2k$, then $2^n-1=(2^k-1)(2^k+1)$. Note that $2^k-1$ and $2^k+1$ are coprime to each other.